# Too many re-renders - an infinite loop in React. How to use React.effect and use fetch?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display data fetched from API with React.

I am fetching the data from https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2, and I intend to display the names and urls retuned and also manipulate them to practice conditional rendering, etc

But it seems that I have run into an infinite loop.

I have googled and it suggests me to use `React.useEffect()` But even if I did this, I still get the errors:

`Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

My code are as below:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PokemonList from "./PokemonList";

function App() {

  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('fetch ran')
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon').then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setPokemons(() => data);
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

PokemonList.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PokemonList({ pokemons }) {

    const [pokemonsArray, setPokemonsArray] = React.useState([]);

    setPokemonsArray(()=>pokemons.results)

    const pokemonsElements = pokemonsArray.map((pokemon) => {
        return (
            <div key={pokemon.name}>
                <h3>{pokemon.name}</h3>
                <p>{pokemon.url}</p>
                <hr />
            </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {pokemonsElements}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Sometimes I would also get the error:

`Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.`
`react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

I assume this is bc I try to run .map() when the data has not been returned yet....

Can anyone help me? Sorry if it is a stupid question but I have been stuck for so long and could not find answers. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: btw, I recommend the use of react-query, https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the state directly inside the component which means that every time the component renders, and its state is updated which causes a re-render and then you set the state again, causing another re-render.

It is exactly as you stated. The reason `map` in `pokemonsArray.map` is being undefined is because it is immediately being accessed before the component is mounted and is ready.

Here is how you would do it by fixing in `App` and `PokemonList`

In `App`, you do not need to make a callback on `setPokemons` as you can directly pass the value.

```
setPokemons(data || [])
```

App:

```js
const [pokemons, setPokemons] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('fetch ran')
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setPokemons(data.results || []);
    })
}, [])
```

Check if `pokemons` is unavailable in which case return null or call a spinner component or similar which shows that the list is empty or being loaded.

`PokemonList`

```js
export default function PokemonList({ pokemons }) {
  if (!pokemons) return null;

  return (<div> {
    pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
      <div key={pokemon.name}>
        <h3>{pokemon.name}</h3>
        <p>{pokemon.url}</p>
        <hr />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

> setPokemonsArray(()=>pokemons.results)

Btw, I recommend the use of react-query.

With RQ:

```
import React from 'react'
import PokemonList from "./PokemonList";

function App() {
  const {data: pokemons} = useQuery(
    queryKey: ['pokemons'],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon').then(
        (res) => res.json(),
      ))

  return (
    <div>
      <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The original question is specifically about understanding and solving the issue with the infinite loop and `react-query` is indeed out of scope. The primary concern was the misuse of state within the component, and it should be addressed directly first.
Introducing a library like `react-query` increases complexity, especially if OP is a beginner or isn't familiar with it. For someone who's just trying to learn the basics of React and state management adding another layer can be overwhelming.